# Conflict using Bootstrap's display property d-none d-md-block and d-flex

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

In the following code block bootstrap classes `d-none d-md-block` are cancelling `d-flex`.
I need to not show this block on anything lower than `md` but also be able to set `d-flex` so that bootstraps `align-self-end` class works, (which currently it does not). How do I get these to play nicely together? Or is there another solution?

```
<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 custom-right d-none d-md-block d-flex">                              
   <h2 class="align-self-end">Title Here</h2>                       
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you shouldn't be using `d-block` at all. Replace it and `d-flex` with `d-md-flex` to apply flex display only to the medium breakpoint and above.

See https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/utilities/flex/#enable-flex-behaviors and https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/utilities/display/#hiding-elements.

Comment: Thanks, it's a bit confusing. The bootstrap docs do say `<div class="d-none d-lg-block">hide on screens smaller than lg</div>` so... that's where that came from.  Your solution worked.

Comment: That's an example for cases where you want to apply block styling. They rarely list all possible permutations of a pattern.